# Simulate button click with loadContent

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

Right now when user want to go back they are required to click a button. Here is the code that generate said button :

```
echo "<button onclick=\"loadContent('client/profile_edit.php?id=182&amp;next_tab=user_records');\" value=\"Back\" type=\"button\" class=\"negative iconstxt icoNegative\"><span>Back</span></button>";
```

Now I want to make it automatic. I want it to redirect automatically. Is there anyway I can simulate button click with PHP? JavaScript redirect does not work mainly because I have problem with this part `client/profile_edit.php`

It's a PHP page inside a page. I'm sorry because I don't know what it's called. Maybe it's a frame?? The redirect code below partially worked:

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.location.href='client/profile_edit.php?id=182&amp;next_tab=user_records';
    </SCRIPT>");
```

I do get redirected to `client/profile_edit.php` but there's no CSS at all. That's mean a page with no styling.

So anyone know how can I simulate button click? Please comment if what I'm wrote does not make any sense/clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simulate the button clicked by using [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) - `document.getElementById("myButton").click();`. Add an `id` to your button, ie. `myButton`,and then this will cause the button to auto click which will invoke your `loadContent()`

Comment: It does worked. Thank you!